# Why does IntelliJ IDEA give java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver error when MySql jar file is added?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, mysql-connector

I get the following error when I try to run a simple program to connect to MySql database in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
    at config.DatabaseConfig.getConnection(DatabaseConfig.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

The following is the code I'm using:

db.properties

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
jdbc.user=user
jdbc.password=password
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
package config;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DatabaseConfig {

    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection != null) {
            return connection;
        } else {
            try {
                // Load database properties
                InputStream inputStream = DatabaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(inputStream);

                // Get properties
                String driver = properties.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
                String url = properties.getProperty("jdbc.url");
                String user = properties.getProperty("jdbc.user");
                String password = properties.getProperty("jdbc.password");

                // Register JDBC driver
                Class.forName(driver);

                // Open a connection
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import config.DatabaseConfig;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize database connection
        Connection connection = DatabaseConfig.getConnection();

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database.");
            // Perform database operations
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to the database.");
        }

        // Close the connection when done
        try {
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. I followed this link: [Database Tools and SQL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mysql.html). I was able to connect to my database and successfully run a test connection. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.
2. I put the MySQL jar file in my project directory: RootFolder/MySql.jar then added to my dependencies as follows: file -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + -> JARs or Directories -> RootFolder/MySql.jar. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.
3. I downloaded the latest MySql.jar file from this link: [MySql Community Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). The version is mysql-connector-j.8.3.0. I added it to my dependencies as follows: file -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + -> JARs or Directories -> C:\Users\me\Downloads\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error. (I tried this with zipped and unzipped jar file)
4. I also tried adding the jar file as a library as follows: file -> Project Structure -> libraries -> + -> Java -> RootFolder/MySql.jar. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.
5. I also tried adding the jar file as a library as follows: file -> Project Structure -> libraries -> + -> Java -> C:\Users\me\Downloads\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.
6. I tried adding the library from Maven as follows: file -> Project Structure -> libraries -> + -> From Maven -> com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.3.0. But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.
7. I followed ALL of the answers on this stackoverflow post: [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database). But when I run Main.java, it prints "Failed to connect to the database" and shows the above error.

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); ` as the first line of `main` will give you a sanity check on your classpath. Incidentally, you can set the [properties directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties))

Comment: The issue cannot be reproduced by following your steps. The project works fine. Here is the complete sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r84k1teejqdtmvhj6vfsr/jdbc-mysql-sample.zip?rlkey=j45ke9nlc9p0s5e9xz1h6uze5&dl=1. Please compare it to yours to see what's different. Screenshot of the working project: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4lfuhpauxdzhn7hjqapnw/idea64_2024-03-08_06-57-28.png?rlkey=7wufq6ii008fpabr03xpada5v&dl=1.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Which step did you follow to make it work?

Comment: Steps 2,3,4 and 5 should all work if the jar is present in the module dependencies.

Comment: What happened when you followed my debug code suggestion?

Comment: @CrazyCoder your sample code won't work for me either. It says the inStream parameter is null. I'm so confused

Comment: @g00se I tried hard coding the driver, username, url, and password but it gave me the same error.

Comment: That's not the question I asked about *code*

Comment: Please post the full output from the Run console in the IDE into your question (including the first line with the java command and classpath).

Comment: Configuring the Database Tools of IntelliJ has nothing to do with adding a JDBC driver to the classpath of your Java program. Those are two separate and unrelated things. In the first case you add the MySQL driver to the classpath of a sub-process of IntelliJ so IntelliJ itself can connect to MySQL. For your program, you need to add the MySQL Connector/J dependency to your Maven pom.xml or Gradle build.gradle file, or if you're manually configuring the classpath, to the classpath of your **module** (F4, modules, select the right module, tab dependencies).

Comment: In any case, if you tried that and it didn't work, please show the details, and also explain exactly how you run your application.

Comment: You'd probably be better off moving to genericize your developing by using Maven in IntelliJ. fwiw [here is your (running for me) code](https://technojeeves.com/tech/sample-maven-jdbc.zip) as a Maven project which you should be able to import into IntelliJ

Comment: @g00se I put the print function in the first line of the code and this is what it returned: C:\Users\me\projects\untitled\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\me\projects\untitled\build\resources\main

Comment: That's progress (of sorts). As you can see, the driver jar is *not* in that classpath. It *should* be. I don't know what IntelliJ does to Maven projects as I don't use it, but I'm guessing that no explicit classpath manipulation will be required, as Maven 'just works'

Comment: Truly recommend to give it a try with Maven and Gradle build tools, they excel in handling dependencies

Comment: Indeed. Unzip that Maven project I gave you and import it

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was using gradle. I tried adding the gradle dependency for mysql but the project would not build because the dependency was not found. I tried implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.31").

Comment: @g00se your sample program ran perfectly. I started a new project using maven instead of gradle. Added the mysql dependency to pom.xml as well as the maven libraries. I used my original code and it ran as intended. Thank you.

Comment: That is because the coordinates are `implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.3.0'` (i.e. `com.mysql`, not `mysql`); you're trying to use a combination of the old and new coordinates, as MySQL in all their wisdom changed things between version 8.0.30 and 8.0.31 from `mysql:mysql-connector-java` to `com.mysql:mysql-connector-j`. N.B. I used the latest version 8.3.0, not the older 8.0.31.